# php's server side associative arrays to html's client side

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

In php I have array with following

```
$var=array();
$var[0][0][num]='1';
$var[0][0][text]='2';
$var[0][1][num]='3';
$var[0][1][text]='4';
$var[1][0][num]='5';
$var[1][0][text]='6';
$var[1][1][num]='7';
$var[1][1][text]='8';
```

I need to move pairs of variables `[text]` and `[num]` up and down and append new pairs into the end of array.

It's simple to do it on server side, but I want to allow these operation on the client side.

So, it should look like folowing

```
<form>
<div>
<input name="var[0][0][num]" value="1">
<input name="var[0][0][text]" value="2">
<input name="var[0][1][num]" value="3">
<input name="var[0][1][text]" value="4">
</div>

<div>
<input name="var[1][0][num]" value="5">
<input name="var[1][0][text]" value="6">
<input name="var[1][1][num]" value="7">
<input name="var[1][1][text]" value="8">
</div>
</form>
```

So, now I need to copy any of these div's into the end of the form and move these divs up and down and keep theirs values.

For example, I can copy upper div and append it to `form`:

```
onlick="this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true))"
```

and form after that looks like:

```
<form>
<div onlick="this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true))">
<input name="var[0][0][num]" value="1">
<input name="var[0][0][text]" value="2">
<input name="var[0][1][num]" value="3">
<input name="var[0][1][text]" value="4">
</div>

<div>
<input name="var[1][0][num]" value="5">
<input name="var[1][0][text]" value="6">
<input name="var[1][1][num]" value="7">
<input name="var[1][1][text]" value="8">
</div>

<div onlick="this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true))">
<input name="var[0][0][num]" value="1">
<input name="var[0][0][text]" value="2">
<input name="var[0][1][num]" value="3">
<input name="var[0][1][text]" value="4">
</div>

</form>
```

I can't figure out, how to change names of copied div's inputs. For example, copied and appended div should be

```
<div onlick="this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true))">
<input name="var[2][0][num]" value="1">
<input name="var[2][0][text]" value="2">
<input name="var[2][1][num]" value="3">
<input name="var[2][1][text]" value="4">
</div>
```

Or, when I move upper div below lower div, they should be renamed and look like

```
<div>
<input name="var[0][0][num]" value="5">
<input name="var[0][0][text]" value="6">
<input name="var[0][1][num]" value="7">
<input name="var[0][1][text]" value="8">
</div>

<div>
<input name="var[1][0][num]" value="1">
<input name="var[1][0][text]" value="2">
<input name="var[1][1][num]" value="3">
<input name="var[1][1][text]" value="4">
</div>
```

Ok, I know that this question is complicated and may look even stupid, so I just need a guess at least =)

Comment: Sounds like a job for javascript, and possibly AJAX to update the changes to the server. Also, the javascript library jQuery (also with AJAX) would be even easier.

Comment: don't move the dom elements, if you need to keep the naming constant. move the VALUES. it'll be a bit more work, but it'd be easier than rebuilding the name attributes each time you do a move.

Comment: @Marc B I'd glad to, but there's possibility, that some divs will have different number of variables (not only `num` and `text` keys)

Comment: @EL Is this question still open?  If not, please upvote any answers that are helpful to you, and choose a correct answer when done (to close the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned jQuery in your tags, but that is what I would look at. Specifically, the jQueryUI library, which runs on top of jQuery.

jQuery is a javascript library that is more efficient (less typing, do more with less code) than classic javascript.

See the jQueryUI sortable widget, [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

For jQuery tutorials: [Alex Garret's jQuery tutorials at the thenewboston.com](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)

[Alex Garret's website](http://phpacademy.org) with many more tutorials.

Comment: Yeah it looks fine, but I'm trying to avoid JQ.

Comment: can you tell, does this JQUI renames inputs names or keeps them unchanged and assign (swap) new values to them?

Comment: You'll have to use either javascript or jQuery for this, and jQuery is frankly much easier to master. I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your second question.